# Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am using PyODBC to back up my database, using following code:

```
SQL_command = """
                BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase]
                TO DISK = N'D:\MSSQL\BACKUP\MyDatabase_20141212.bak' WITH
                      NOFORMAT
                ,     NOINIT
                ,     NAME = N'MyDatabase_20141212'
                ,     SKIP
                ,     REWIND
                ,     NOUNLOAD
                ,     STATS = 10
              """

conn.cursor.execute(SQL_command)

conn.cursor.commit()
```

The above code give me an error message:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
>
> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
> Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot perform a backup or restore operation
> within a transaction. (3021) (SQLExecDirectW);
>
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]BACKUP DATABASE is
> terminating abnormally. (3013)')

I tried to run the SQL code in SQL Server, and it works fine.

May I know what is wrong with my code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error says

> Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.

Transactions are started by default in pyodbc, so how do you execute a query without creating a transaction? Simply turn on autocommit:

```
conn.autocommit = true
// do stuff
conn.autocommit = false
```

The pyodbc FAQ has [an entry about this](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/FAQs#Catalog_procedure_'xxx'_can_not_be_run_in_a_transactio).

Comment: This works for pymssql as well

Answer (score 4):

By default all pyodbc connections start with a transaction.

You need to turn autocommit on - using the autocommit keyword to the connect function:

```
conn.autocommit = true
```

Comment: This works for pymssql as well

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct. You do need to set autocommit. However, the transaction will complete but the backup won't actually be taken because of a quirk in SQL Server and the way it returns status messages for backup and restore operations.

To work around this you need to loop through these return messages until none remain:

```
SQL_command = """
                BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase]
                TO DISK = N'D:\MSSQL\BACKUP\MyDatabase_20141212.bak' WITH
                      NOFORMAT
                ,     NOINIT
                ,     NAME = N'MyDatabase_20141212'
                ,     SKIP
                ,     REWIND
                ,     NOUNLOAD
                ,     STATS = 10
              """

conn.cursor.execute(SQL_command)
while conn.cursor.nextset():
     pass 

conn.cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

With me it works fine like this:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    result = cursor.execute(
                 """SELECT command FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
                 WHERE command LIKE 'BACKUP%'").fetchone()
    if not result:
        break
```