# Cannot RESTORE within a transaction; autocommit is on

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm using `sqlalchemy` with `pyodbc` to restore a `mssql` ".bak" file. I've followed advice from previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443414/cannot-perform-a-backup-or-restore-operation-within-a-transaction) regarding getting around transactions but it doesn't seem to change anything. Any help would be appreciated.

```python
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

params = quote_plus("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                    "Server=Computer\SQLEXPRESS;"
                    "Database=master;"
                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
connection = engine.raw_connection()

db_path = r"C:\\Path\\to\\OutputDB.bak"
move_path = r"C:\\Path\\to\\backup\\db.mdf"
move_log_path = r"C:\\Path\\to\\backup\\db_Log.ldf"

sql_cmd = f"""
    RESTORE DATABASE [db]
    FROM DISK = N'{db_path}'
    WITH FILE = 1,
    MOVE N'db'
    TO N'{move_path}',
    MOVE N'test_log'
    TO N'{move_log_path}',
    RECOVERY,
    NOUNLOAD,
    REPLACE,
    STATS = 5
"""


connection.autocommit = True

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(sql_cmd)
while cursor.nextset():
    pass

connection.autocommit = False
```

I get the below error message:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction. (3021) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (3013)')

Comment: passing `connect_args={'autocommit': True}` to `create_engine` seems to work. Why doesn't `connection.autocommit = True` work?

Comment: the docs for sqlalchemy recommend using `Connection.execution_options()`. "Full control of the “autocommit” behavior is available using the generative Connection.execution_options() method provided on Connection, Engine, Executable, using the “autocommit” flag which will turn on or off the autocommit for the selected scope. " Have you tried this? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit
`cursor.execute(text(sql_cmd).execution_options(autocommit=True))`

Comment: Using `cursor.execute(sql_cmd).execution_options(autocommit=True)` still results in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by passing `connect_args={'autocommit': True}` to `create_engine`. Neither `cursor.execute(sql_cmd).execution_options(autocommit=True)` or `connection.autocommit = True` appeared to work.

```python
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

params = quote_plus("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                    "Server=Computer\SQLEXPRESS;"
                    "Database=master;"
                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, connect_args={'autocommit': True})
connection = engine.raw_connection()

db_path = r"C:\\Path\\to\\OutputDB.bak"
move_path = r"C:\\Path\\to\\backup\\db.mdf"
move_log_path = r"C:\\Path\\to\\backup\\db_Log.ldf"

sql_cmd = f"""
    RESTORE DATABASE [db]
    FROM DISK = N'{db_path}'
    WITH FILE = 1,
    MOVE N'db'
    TO N'{move_path}',
    MOVE N'test_log'
    TO N'{move_log_path}',
    RECOVERY,
    NOUNLOAD,
    REPLACE,
    STATS = 5
"""

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(sql_cmd)
while cursor.nextset():
    pass
```